# How to retrieve many radio button value with different name and value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have many radio buttons with different name and value like this

```
<div>    
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="1" value="A" />
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="1" value="B" />
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="1" value="C" />
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="1" value="D" />
</div>

<div>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="2" value="A" />
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="2" value="B" />
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="2" value="C" />
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="2" value="D" />
</div>
```

and so on like 40 radio button. I save radio's name and value with sessionStorage like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function()
    {
        sessionStorage.setItem($(this).prop('name'), $(this).val());
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < sessionStorage.length; i++) {
        var key   = sessionStorage.key(i);
        var value = sessionStorage.getItem(key);

        $("#radio"+key).val(function(){
            $(this).attr("checked", value);
        });
    }

});
```

Checked status returned but radio's value always returned same for all radio's button.

Comment: ID's need to be unique by the way

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lvmvky3u/ - it does work by the way, when I inspect the local storage I'm seeing the desired output

Comment: It does work with save state but when I try to retrieve the value, it just returned with same value for all radios

Comment: can you show the error as I'm not seeing that

Comment: There's no error, it just all returned with "A" value for all radios

Comment: What I mean is, I can't see that happening, can you replicate it in a jsFiddle?

Comment: I'll show you the image when I clicked for save state and after refresh the page result. Before https://ibb.co/eAG3mw, after refresh https://ibb.co/n8aw6w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this  https://jsfiddle.net/Lvmvky3u/1/,

remove the `Id` to `class`, `id` only refers to a unique element

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {
    sessionStorage.setItem($(this).prop('name'), $(this).val());
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < sessionStorage.length; i++) {
    var key = sessionStorage.key(i);
    var value = sessionStorage.getItem(key);

    $(".radio" + key).filter('[value='+value+']').prop('checked', true);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue may lie in the fact that you have multiple elements with the same id. Giving each radio button its own unique ID should solve your issue.

*EDIT ->
This issue arises from the fact that elements are quite often identified by their 'id' this leads to problems where instead of applying changes to/getting information from an element with a specific 'id', you edit/get information from the last element with that 'id'.

Comment: You should probably explain how would that solve the problem. If you can't, this should have been a comment

Comment: Its okay. I named it with different id as well but instead returned with "A" value for all radios, now it returned with "D" value for all radios

Answer (score 0):

**I checked your code and it’s giving me the expected result.**

But there is wrong with your for loop. It giving null value for the first radio button. So you can use `value="" checked`  for give default values.

```
 <div>
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="1" value="A" value="" checked />
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="1" value="B" />
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="1" value="C" />
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="1" value="D" />
</div>
```